# What is the maximum of number of arguments for varargs in java?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-languages

What is the maximum of number of arguments which can be used by a vararg in java ?
I believe there should be some limit and it is not infinite.

Comment: If you're ever passing anywhere close to that number of parameters (around `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) via var-args, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @berry120 Although it is a somewhat theoretical question, it is not uninteresting.

Comment: Note that all answers that tell a number greater 64K are wrong, no matter how many upvotes they got.

Comment: @Ingo Which answers? ;-)

Answer (score 37):

A method (including the static class initializer) can have at most 64k. If the arguments are such that they can be pushed with a single bytecode that is 1 byte long each, you can have something about **64000** arguments on a call.

Comment: Ah! I didn't knew of that. Didn't took into consideration the method size actually. But I can't delete my answer, as it is accepted. :( Still I'll give you a +1. Thanks, I learnt something new. :)

Comment: @RohitJain No issues. I actually ran into this when I once tried to make a huge static array containing a parser table. I had to split the array initialization in different static initialization methods, but of course you can't split a method invocation....

Comment: and what about `main(String... params)`? can i pass more parameters from the command line?

Comment: @piotrek Probably yes, unless your shell doesn't support it. Nowadays the limits are loose, but I remember times when the usual space for command line arguments was 4k. But then it is no Java issue anymore in a strict sense. Should also be easy to test, just run a shell script that creates 100,000 files or so, and then run your java prog with argument *

Comment: @Ingo "at most 64k" – can you elaborate? Is that some JVM specification limit or otherwise specified?

Comment: MC emperor yes it is.

Comment: @Ingo Could you provide a link to the specs?

Comment: MC Emperor see the JVM spec, obtainable on the web.

Comment: A vararg is one array as an argument.

Comment: @PeterLawrey are you sure you understood the question and my answer?

Comment: By the way, *variable arity parameter* seems to be the technical name for varargs in the [Java SE Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). But I could not find any details about limits.