# Are there any programming languages that limit the number of arguments to a function?

Tags: language-design

And by limit I mean something reasonably low (let's say less than 64) so as to exclude C etc.

Answer (score 1):

Java is limited to 255: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30581726/4698922

> The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of
>   a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for
>   this in the case of instance or interface method invocations.

Answer (score 1):

C90 is limited to:

```
—127 parameters in one function definition
—127 arguments in one function call
—127 parameters in one macro definition
—127 arguments in one macro invocation
```

At minimum. Implementations can support more, but 'portable' code can only rely on 127.