# Data binding - ActivityMainBinding.java error: too many parameters

Tags: java, android, binding

recently I have discovered DataBinding on Android. It was working great, I have followed some guides, but it works until my project gets more elements inside the view. Once a certain amount is reached I get:

[image: Output]

I can notice that every element I add to the view gets generated property in ActivityMainBinding.java seems like I have reached some limit?

The whole xml is surrounded by

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


</layout>
```

I have searched through google and here, but no one seems to have similar problem. It is strictly related to the element count - I add one more and it throws an error.
Please give me some advice or workaround.

Comment: Share some code, share logcat please. It's not possible to provide solution by this question right now.

Comment: Thank you so much for intrest. Isn't that related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581531/maximum-number-of-parameters-in-java-method-declaration

Comment: I don't think so that it's related to your issue.

Comment: You think so? This is the part from ActivityMainBinding.java

https://pastebin.com/CRR2V6UD

Is there a way to exclude some elements from being auto generated in that constructor?

Comment: You might be passing more params to somewhere it expects less. That's why i asked you about code & logcat.

Comment: I can paste code, but xml is kind of very long. Please see here, if I add one more imageButton or any other element, it throws that error:

[link]
https://ibb.co/eseROe

Answer (score 1):

if your using Android Gradle plugin version 3.1.0-alpha06 and higher version  add the following option to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

Previous versions of the data binding compiler generated the binding classes in the same step that compiles your managed code. If your managed code fails to compile, you might get multiple errors reporting that the binding classes aren't found. The new data binding compiler prevents these errors by generating the binding classes before the managed compiler builds your app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with such a complex xml file which had nested scrollview. I fixed the issue by dividing xml file into another layouts and include them in one file by referring.

Let's say you have a main_layout.xml file which you are working on it. Create another xml files by taking out the appropriate sections. Example,

## main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lytFirstContent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/first_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lytSecondContent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lytFirstContent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/second_content"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
        
</RelativeLayout>
```

## first_content.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Your other views -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    
        
</RelativeLayout>
```

## second_content.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Your other views -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    
        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes its works, but not a way to solve problem.