# Is there a limit for number of parameter list Scala 3 function can have?

Tags: scala

I am reading a great book [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0997148004) by Martin Odersky (creator of Scala) and others.

There comes up the chapter `9.3 Currying` where *currying* is introduced. This leads me to the question, **is there some limit to the number of parameter lists a Scala 3 function can have?** Follow-up question: if there is/n't a limit, why?

---

For example, the following Scala 3 snippet compiles just fine.
There is a function `curriedSum` with 5 parameter lists (it is only for illustration, every sane programmer would use a single parameter list).

```scala
def curriedSum(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int)(d: Int)(e: Int) = a + b + c + d + e
curriedSum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) // 15
```

version without *currying*

```
def ordinarySum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int) = a + b + c + d + e
ordinarySum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // 15
```

Comment: If there is a limit is far from anything practical and realistic, so I wouldn't care.

Comment: From JVM point of view both versions of `curriedSum`/`ordinarySum` have 5 parameters. There is JVM limit how many parameters a method can have totally.

Comment: It's 255 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581531/maximum-number-of-parameters-in-java-method-declaration So there can be no more than 255 parameter lists if they are single-parameter or 128 lists if they are two-parameter etc.