# Kotlin listOf function: what is max count of arguments?

Tags: kotlin

I have a big list of strings. It contains about 100000 strings. These strings are relatively short: medium length is about 60 characters, the maximum length is about 300 characters. I want to hardcode this list in a source code of my application. I want to use listOf function:

```
val cities = listOf(
"Boston",
"Munich",
"Saint-Petersburg")
```

My code will be similar but listOf function will contain 100000 arguments. Is such code correct? 
Can Kotlin compiler compile correctly function call with 100000 arguments?

Comment: About 64,000 max according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164255/what-is-the-maximum-of-number-of-arguments-for-varargs-in-java).

Comment: I don't know about this subject, but I suspect there are multiple different constraints you may violate with so many hard-coded strings, not just the limit on vararg length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have something about 64K arguments on a call.
It is better you read this list with For-Loop from config file near your running file.

Comment: Do you have a source for the 64k arguments?