# Convert a Java Object to a List of an Object

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to convert a java object into a a List of Object. My current object is the ff.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public final class GetCreditCardInfo {

    @JsonAlias("ns:return")
    private List<CreditCardDetails> details;

    @JsonAlias("ns:return")
    private CreditCardDetails detailsObject;

}
```

What the code does above is get the object or list of objects in the response. I plan on just converting an object into a List of objects if the details variable doesnt have a value at all.

I'm doing this since our southbound APIs throw either an Object or a List of Objects seen below.

[image]

For the existing implementation that I have, I just want to just convert the object into a List so that if the API threw an Object response. My existing implementation for a List of Object would still work since the api that threw an object will still be read as a single List of object in my API. Is there a way to convert my Object to List of Objects?

Comment: `return List.of(myObj);` this can helps you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
List.of( myCreditCardDetails )
```

## `List.of`

Java 9 and later provides several handy [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of()) methods on the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface for instantiating an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

To make an unmodifiable list containing a single object:

```
List< CreditCardDetails > list = List.of( myCreditCardDetails ) ;
```

To make an empty unmodifiable list:

```
List< CreditCardDetails > list = List.of() ;
```

To make an unmodifiable list containing multiple objects:

```
List< CreditCardDetails > list = List.of( aliceCreditCardDetails , bobCreditCardDetails , carolCreditCardDetails , davisCreditCardDetails ) ;
```

You can pass up to around 64,000 elements according to [*What is the maximum of number of arguments for varargs in java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18164255/642706).

To make an unmodifiable list from an array:

```
List< CreditCardDetails > list = List.of( arrayOfCreditCardDetailsObjects ) ;
```

To make an unmodifiable list copied from a modifiable list, call [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

```
List< CreditCardDetails > list = List.copyOf( otherModifiableList ) ;
```